# How to know whether Couchbase updated or inserted a record using UPSERT

Tags: java-8, couchbase

I am using Couchbase java SDK to read and write data. Currently I am having large number of records which need to be saved in Couchbase. These records contains both new or existing one.

I am using [Bucket.upsert](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.2.4/com/couchbase/client/java/Bucket.html#upsert-D-) for this functionality. But I also need to capture that how many records are created or updated into Couchbase.

How to achieve this effectively? The following is my pseudo code that I am having now

```
JsonDocument doc = bucket.get("docId")
if (doc != null) {
    // Perform update
    updatedCount++;
} else {
    // perform insert
    insertedCount++;
}
```

Any thought to do this better way. Because I am having more than 500k records to save into Couchbase.

Comment: Instead of using a `get` to see if a document exists, you should use the `exists` method - http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.7.1/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately we don't currently expose whether an UPSERT does an insert or an update.

If you are willing to take a bit of a performance hit, you can do an insert directly followed by an update if the insert fails, and track how often the insert fails. That should give you some indication of how often an upsert would do insert as opposed to update.

If that's too big a performance hit, you could do the two-step operation in 1/1000 or 1/1,000,0000 operations. That should keep the performance penalty manageable while generating useful information.

Comment: Is it possible to upsert collection of documents into Couchbase?

Comment: Yes it is. As you can see from this page (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/upsert.html) an UPSERT statement can have multiple key-value pairs (in the "values-clause").